# Get Field Names from Sap.Data.Hana.HanaDataRader

Tags: .net, hana

This seems like it should be simple to achieve but after scouring the internet, I can't for the life of me work out how to get the field names from the data set that is returned when using the SAP HANA .NET Connector.

This is a simple requirement so I am hoping someone out there knows the way.

Obviously this becomes imperative when dealing with larger queries that involve joins and other dynamically derived fields in the resulting dataset.

```
static void DoExtract()
{
    var connectionString = $"Server={_server}:36013;Database={_database};UserName={_username};Password={_password}";

    // Connect to the Hana instance.
    var hanaConnection = new HanaConnection(connectionString);
    hanaConnection.Open();

    // Create the command and call query the DB.
    var hanaCommand = new HanaCommand("SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM SAPECP.EBAN", hanaConnection);
    var hanaDataReader = hanaCommand.ExecuteReader();

    // ---------------------------------------------------
    // GET THE HEADER NAMES HERE ...
    // ---------------------------------------------------

    // Read each record and display the results.
    while (hanaDataReader.Read())
    {
        var values = string.Empty; 

        for (int i = 0; i < hanaDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                values += "\t";

            var value = hanaDataReader.GetFieldValue<dynamic>(i);
            values += $"{value.ToString()}";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(values);
    }

    // Close the connection.
    hanaConnection.Close();

    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: What means "get field names"? You are querying names in select string and don't know their names? Unclear

Comment: @Suncatcher I think it’s clear. The query could be dynamically generated with joins on multiple tables or it could be select *, that being the case, I need to be able to get the names of the fields in the correct order from the resulting data set, I can’t rely on the query string itself. This is standard sort of stuff, in ADO or any other ODBC style connector, to other DB’s I can do that. Make sense?